# No data visible on view when requesting to an API

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to retrieve a list of users from an API. I had several errors like

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type
>   'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Array

or

> Cannot read property 'id' of undefined” when parsing an array declared
>   in a factory

Now I worked around these errors but the problem now is, that the errors are gone but I don't see any data in my view.The page is just empty. I really have no idea what I could try further. The strange thing is that I can log my data in get (users) and also see the 200 success in my network tab but I can't get it work in my view.

This is my service:

```
getList(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<{results: any[]}>(`${this.url}/users`)
    .pipe(
      retry(2),
     // catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

page.ts

```
 userList: any[] = [];
...
ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllUsers(); // get the users wenn view intializes
}

getAllUsers() {
  // get saved list of users
  this.userService.getList().subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response);
    this.userList = response.results;
  });
  }
```

page.html

```
<ion-list>

          <ion-item lines="none" *ngFor="let user of userList.results">

              <ion-avatar>
                  <ion-img src="assets/friends1.jpeg"> </ion-img>
              </ion-avatar>


                  <h2 class="title">{{user.username}}</h2>

           </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

the log of my response is:

> results: (8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already assigning the results to the userList so it is already an array and wont have a results property. Change userList.results to just userList in your ngFor

```
*ngFor="let user of userList"
```

It is also better to use the async pipe rather than subscribing, change your component to be

```
userList$ = this.userService.getList().pipe(map(response => response.results));
```

and in your template use the async pipe

```
*ngFor="let user of (userList$ | async)"
```

Comment: but I would have to define userList as `userList$: Observable<any[]>;` and I still have to add `this` in the func. `getAllUsers() {
  this.userList$ = this.userService.getList().pipe(map(response => response.results));
  }` With these changes I get again this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

Comment: This is the only line you need, it replaces everything you have in page.ts listed above.

Comment: There is nothing in your question that shows what is causing TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined